# What does "$A \leq B : \Longleftrightarrow A \subseteq B$ is an order relation of $\mathcal{P}(N)$" mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, definition, relations, order-theory

I have read the following in some exercise for discrete mathematics.
Let $N$ be a set and $\mathcal{P}(N)$ be its power set. Then $A \leq B : \Longleftrightarrow A \subseteq B$ is an order relation of $\mathcal{P}(N)$.

I am not really sure what is asked here. I know how to show that $\subseteq$ is a **partial** order on the power set but I am not sure what exactly is asked here. What order relation do I need to show and what should I do with $A \leq B$?

Comment: voting to reopen. question is clear enough

Comment: @LuisFelipe: thank you! I am confused why it was closed, it is basic Discrete Maths, so I didn't think it was necessary to provide any background.

Comment: Here, if you post any doubt on "basic math" , it will be closed by selfish people. But If you post "high level math" , you will get a lot of upvotes from people who doesn't understand what you wrote.

Comment: @LuisFelipe: unfortunately that is true. But thank god there also enough nice people here (you being one of them:))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A binary relation $\leq$ over a set $X$ is an *[order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)* if the following hold:

1. $\leq$ is *reflexive*, i.e. $n \leq n$ for all $n \in X$;
2. $\leq$ is *antisymmetric*, i.e. if $n \leq m$ and $m \leq n$ then $n = m$, for all $n,m \in X$;
3. $\leq$ is *transitive*, i.e. if $n \leq m$ and $m \leq \ell$ then $n \leq \ell$, for all $n, m, \ell \in X$.

Often an order relation on $X$ is called *partial* to distinguish it from a *total* order, which is an order on $X$ such that, for all $n,m \in X$, one has $n \leq m$ or $m \leq n$.

You are asked to prove that $\subseteq$ is a reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive relation on $\mathcal{P}(N)$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

A "ordered set" is a shortcut for "partially ordered set", so you must prove the 3 axioms of a ordered relation. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).